# PySpark unzip files: Which is a good approach for unzipping files and storing the csv files into a Delta Table?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, zip, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have zip files stored in Amazon s3 then I have a Python list as `["s3://mybucket/file1.zip", ..., "s3://mybucket/fileN.zip"]`, I need to unzip all these files using a Spark Cluster, and stored all the CSV files into a delta format table. I would like to know a faster processing approach than my current approach:

1) I have a **bucle for** for iterating in my Python list.

2) I'm obtaining the zip files from s3 using Python Boto3 `s3.bucket.Object(file)`

3) I'm unzipping the files using the next code

```
import io
import boto3
import shutil
import zipfile
for file in ["s3://mybucket/file1.zip", ..., "s3://mybucket/fileN.zip"]:
    obj = s3.bucket.Object(file)
    with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
        tf.seek(0)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
            for subfile in zipf.namelist():
                zipf.extract(subfile, outputZip)
    dbutils.fs.cp("file:///databricks/driver/{0}".format(outputZip), "dbfs:" + outputZip, True)
    shutil.rmtree(outputZip)
    dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:" + outputZip, True)
```

4) My files are unzipped in the Driver Node, then the executors can't reach these files (I don't find a way to do it) so I move all these csv files to DBFS using `dbutils.fs.cp()`

5) I read all the csv files from DBFS using a Pyspark Dataframe and I write that into a Delta table

```
df = self.spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("dbfs:" + file) 
df.write.format("delta").save(path)
```

6) I delete the data from DBFS and the Driver Node

So, my current goal is to ingest zip files from S3 into a Delta table in less time than my previous process. I suppose that I can parallelize some of these processes as the 1) step, I would like to avoid the copy step to DBFS because I don't need to have the data there, also I need to remove the CSV files after each ingests into a Delta Table to avoid a memory error in the Driver Node disk. Any advice?

Comment: Depends on your CSV files that can works: df = spark.read.csv("s3://bucket/file.csv.zip", sep=',')

Answer (score 1):

Well, Multiple possible solutions could be:

1. You can read all the files together (if schema allows it) with `df=spark.read.csv("s3://mybucket")`  and write the dataframe as delta with `df.write.format("delta").save(path)`
2. You can read each file individually in dataframe and append to existing delta table (even if it is empty) directly without storing it in DBFS. For more details: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#append-using-dataframes
3. You can read each file individually in dataframe and union it into existing main dataframe. In the end, You can write main dataframe as delta table.

Option 3 would be something like:

```
    import io
    import boto3
    import shutil
    import zipfile
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("name").getOrCreate()

    schema = StructType([
    \\ YOUR DATA SCHMEA
    ])

    df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

    for file in ["s3://mybucket/file1.zip", ..., "s3://mybucket/fileN.zip"]:
        obj = s3.bucket.Object(file)
        with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as tf:
            tf.seek(0)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(tf, mode='r') as zipf:
                for subfile in zipf.namelist():
                    zipf.extract(subfile, outputZip)
        tempdf = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(outputZip)
        df = df.union(tempdf)      

    df.write.format("delta").save(path)
```

Comment: I tried the first solution but the schema does not allow to read as dataframe. The third option can you write a code example?

Comment: @EricBellet Updated Answer with code example for Option 3

Comment: Do you think that it is possible to change the for bucle by a Spark map method?

Comment: @EricBellet If I understood correctly, you want to remove for loop and replace it with spark MAP method. There is no need to use spark to iterate/map over list of S3 paths. You can use python lambda functions OR pandas map to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes, I mean a map method but running in parallel

Comment: Ahh. Ok. I don't think so because on Union into single dataframe

Comment: I see I would like to parallelize that part because I have a lot of .zip files

Comment: What is outputZip here in code?

Answer (score 1):

Zip as you know by now is not a splittable compression technique, there are no built-in codecs that work with zip. You may find some clever person has written their own Spark zip codec/data source, but I haven't found it yet.

A few tips I picked up recently:

1. The aws cli will copy files in parallel to local node (driver or worker). It is much faster to run `aws cp <src> <dst>` than to stream the binary file using `aws cp <src> -`. aws cli / `boto` is much faster (but a little bit harder to use) than the `dbutils.fs.cp()`
2. Using a `for` loop is a good sign of non-parallel execution and inefficiencies. This will lead to lower throughput, higher costs, lower cluster utilization. Use the functional capabilities of Spark and Python where ever possible.
3. You can create a Spark DataFrame of files names with something like:

```
df_files = spark.createDataFrame(dbutils.fs.ls("<s3 path to bucket and folder>"))
```

from this data frame you can run a pandas udf, the `.pipe()` operator, a regular UDF.

4. Running a spark `.pipe()` or a Pandas UDF, in parallel, across a set of workers, each working off the path of the file would let you get more throughput, keeping your cluster busy.
5. Experiment with the PandasUDF to perform either:
   a. copy-unzip-copy back to s3, read with CSV reader
   b. copy-unzip-read-return-in-a-pandas-udf.
   Watch the Ganglia metrics to ensure a high utilization rate.
6. Since you're writing to a Delta table, you can reliably run your writes (appends) in parallel if you have to have multiple spark jobs. [parallel workers in one job >> parallel spark jobs]
7. Supplying a schema to your CSV read 2x faster than `.option("inferSchema","true")`